# Display value in a <c:forEach> loop

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I am using Spring MVC 3. From my controller I set value

```
mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("reports");
mav.addObject("ReportList", ReportList);
return mav;
```

In JSP

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${ReportList}">
   $(list.name)
</c:forEach>
```

**ReportList** has a size of 7. **ReportList** is a list of **Report** class having **name** as instance with proper getters and setters.

When I run it in browser it displays `$(list.name)` 7 times.

Its not displaying proper names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These brackets: { }

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${ReportList}">
   ${list.name}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: But beware that `${}` does not escape the value it outputs, unlike `<c:out />`. It's a shame :/

Answer (score 2):

It should be `${list.name}` ...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `<c:out>` tag to render the value of the `name` attribute. `#{list.name}` might work as well (replace `(` with `{`).

Comment: @TimBüthe It's better to use <c:out> because it escapes special characters, so you can have for example "<tr>" as printed value and it doesn't influence html code of the page.

Comment: It depends on what list.name can return. IMHO its more readable when you don't have c:out and h:outputText all over the place, but it maybe a good idea to prevent xss and the like...

Comment: @TimBüthe That's right that it depends, but if you don't want to use `<c:out>`, IMHO if name could contain chars that should be escaped, you should use `fn:escapeXml` then.

Comment: I guess it all comes down to your preference: `${fn:escapeXml("myStringThatNeedsEscaping<br />")}` or `<c:out value="${"myStringThatNeedsEscaping<br />"}" />`.